# Is it right to 'Hmmm'?

Tags: conversation, abbreviations

While in a online conversation(by typing), how do you let know the other person that you are there listening to him/her? I suppose it would be annoying to type 'okay' or 'yes' all the time and right now, I use 'Hmmm' or 'mmm' as if I am nodding my head to what he says. I am not sure this is the right way or is there something better?

Comment: Use * I'm listening * to let the other person know that you're still there. I use "Hmmm" when I'm thinking about the subject.

Comment: You could also use *ah* or *I see*.

Comment: Is it me or this question has a subjective flavour? There are many ways to say this same thing, even _uh-uh_.

Comment: I ask if they're still there. I'm obnoxious like that. I also state the obvious betimes. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The normal way to respond to the <strike>bore</strike> person on the other end is to type something that is an intelligent response to whatever that person is <strike>bloviating</strike> talking about. Useless interjections don't do much except break up the flow, especially in multi-party chats.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not correct. "Hmm" would imply that you're either thinking about it, or it can also sound that you are in some way suspicious of what's being discussed.

Generally, the accepted way to show that you're listening without making any specific commentary is to say things like "yeah" and "go on" whilst they're talking, especially during a pause. It sounds much more like you're listening and paying attention than a "hmm" does.

Comment: Actually if you say "yeah", it might sound like a comment, no? It sounds like you're approving...

Comment: ...If I'm talking to someone, aren't they supposed to be thinking about what I say?

Answer (score 1):

"go on", "do tell", "you don't say"...

Comment: There's an old vaudeville comedy routine (Spike Jones used it in his version of *Chloe*) that I really like.  There's a telephone on the stage; it rings, and the comedian answers; we only hear his side of the conversation: "You don't say?  You don't say. You don't say!"  He hangs up; his partner asks "Who was it?" "He didn't say."  The phone rings again; he answers.  "You don't say?  You don't say. You don't say!" Hangs up again; again "Who was it?"  "The same guy."